# YouTube giving me error while using file_get_contents

Tags: json, youtube, youtube-api

So I'm trying to update YouTube code from API v2 to v3, but file_get_contents() keep on giving me an error.

**This is my code:**

```
stream_context_set_default(['http' => ['ignore_errors' => true]]);
$url = file_get_contents('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=contentDetails&playlistId=PLwC9H0qrxrLyQsNFq37MeivYOMOBxfCdo&key=MY_API_KEY');
echo $url;
```

**This is the error message I've been thrown**

```
stdClass Object
(
    [error] => stdClass Object
        (
            [errors] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [domain] => usageLimits
                            [reason] => accessNotConfigured
                            [message] => Access Not Configured. The API (YouTube Data API) is not enabled for your project. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your configuration.
                            [extendedHelp] => https://console.developers.google.com
                        )

                )

            [code] => 403
            [message] => Access Not Configured. The API (YouTube Data API) is not enabled for your project. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your configuration.
        )

)
```

I have set up a new API project and even refreshed my key. I honestly dont know what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to enable the YouTube Data API in the [developers console](https://console.developers.google.com). You can do that by clicking on your project and going to APIs & auth > APIs. There, you search for YouTube Data API and enable it by clicking Enable API.

You should now be able to access YouTube Data API endpoints with your project.

Comment: Oh my god, I feel like a complete idiot.. That did the trick, thank you so much. Since you answered my question first, I marked your question as the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the YouTube data API enabled for your project.

Go into the developer console, select your project and then select 'APIs & auth' and then APIs. You will get a page with a list of Popular APIs. Select the YouTube Data API and click 'Enable API'.

Comment: Oh my god, I feel like a complete idiot.. That did the trick, thank you so much. Since you answered my question first, I did not marked your question as the solution, but you sure should've earned some points! :D